# I am trying to print multiple lines at once, with each line having a delayed print of a set speed in python 2.7.11

Tags: python, python-2.7, printf

Basically,

Delay Print 1

Multiple lines at once test.

The big brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.

Should all print at the same time, while using this function

```
import time
import sys

text_speed = raw_input("What speed? > ")

def delay_print(s):
    for c in s:
        sys.stdout.write(c)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        if text_speed == "fast":
            time.sleep(0.075)

        elif text_speed == "slow":
            time.sleep(.275)

        elif text_speed == "normal":
            time.sleep(.175)

delay_print("Delay Print 1 \n")
delay_print("Multiple lines at once test. \n")
delay_print("The big brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. \n")
```

Is that possible?

When I run it, it will delay print each string one after the other, but I can't seem to find a way to make all 3 lines print at once. Even without the delay print.

Comment: What do you mean print all three at once? They have to be printed in some order. You could concatenate the strings together and then print out one big string.

Comment: @RedKnite I mean I want each line to print simultaneously, one on top of the other. Preferably with the delay_print function but I understand that may not be possible. It's for a text game I'm working on, I just thought it would look cooler than delay printing one line at a time.

Answer (score 0):

well it depends, the thing that is happening right now is that you are giving the order to execute 3 times the function with different attributes, but if I did understand you, you want to execute these 3 functions in a parallel way to each other so here is a reading you can use on multiprocessing http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html
I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you would make it 3 lines, but the program from [this github link](http://github.com/yunabe/codelab/blob/master/misc/terminal_progressbar/progress.py)
makes a progress bar in the console, and there are things after the part that moves, so you might be able to find a way to also add a new line in this setup.

```
import math
import sys
import time

END = 170

MAX_LEN = 30

def get_progressbar_str(progress):
    BAR_LEN = int(MAX_LEN * progress)
    return ('[' + '=' * BAR_LEN +
            ('>' if BAR_LEN < MAX_LEN else '') +
            ' ' * (MAX_LEN - BAR_LEN) +
            '] %.1f%%' % (progress * 100.))

for i in range(END + 1):
    time.sleep(0.01)
    progress = 1.0 * i / END
    sys.stderr.write('\r\033[K' + get_progressbar_str(progress))
    sys.stderr.flush()
sys.stderr.write('\n')
sys.stderr.flush()
```

you might want to put this at the end so the console doesn't close out after.

```
while True:
    time.sleep(1)
```

note: this has to be ran from a .py file, not from idle to see the progress bar properly.

Comment: This answer won't actually work but I found a website that can help you: [terminal apps Python](http://introtopython.org/terminal_apps.html) I would do something like `os.system('clear)` and then add the new text.